# How can all columns of a dataframe be converted into a single list in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, flextable

This is an obscure request. I'm trying to do conditional formatting in flextable for an RMarkdown document, and long story short, I need a **list** of values derived from a dataframe.

Here's an example of a dataframe:

```
df <- tibble(COL_1 = c(1, 2, 3),
             COL_2 = c("A", "B", "C"),
             COL_3 = c("Peach", "Plum", "Pear"))

> df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  COL_1 COL_2 COL_3
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1 A     Peach
2     2 B     Plum 
3     3 C     Pear
```

I am looking for code to achieve the following (I'm agnostic to the type of the values):

```
"1", "2", "3", "A", "B", "C", "Peach", "Plum", "Pear"
```

Anyone have a solution? Bonus points if it's dplyr friendly.

Also, if anyone has a neat, clean way to format the color and background of a lot of values in a lot of columns in flextable, I'd appreciate the help. I doubt the solution I'm pursuing is optimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unlist` will helps

```
df %>% unlist %>% as.vector
[1] "1"     "2"     "3"     "A"     "B"     "C"     "Peach" "Plum"  "Pear"
```

Comment: Perfect solution, and bonus points for it fitting into my dplyr pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to change to matrix and collapse in a vector with `c`.

```
library(magrittr)

df %>% as.matrix() %>% c
#[1] "1"     "2"     "3"     "A"     "B"     "C"     "Peach" "Plum"  "Pear"
```

Answer (score 1):

We may `stack` and `pull` the values

```
library(dplyr)
stack(df) %>% 
   pull(values)
#[1] "1"     "2"     "3"     "A"     "B"     "C"     "Peach" "Plum"  "Pear"
```

Comment: Stack was the function I was originally looking for, thank you. This is probably the most intuitive approach, especially from the perspective of someone reading the code.